# Calculate difference in months from timestamps

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, pandas

Assume I have 2 timestamp

```
a=Timestamp('1986-03-31 00:00:00', tz=None)
b=Timestamp('1986-04-18 00:00:00', tz=None)
```

Now if I simply take the difference `b-a` I will get `datetime.timedelta(18)`.

How can I get the difference of the month, which is `1`. No matter how many actual days are between them, I need the difference in `month`. There is a function `SAS` does exactly what I need, `intck('month',a,b)=1`. Is there anything equivalent in python , or pandas/numpy ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I would convert these to pandas [Periods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#period) instead of Timestamps and then diff these

```
>>> a=Timestamp('1986-03-31 00:00:00', tz=None).to_period(freq='M')
>>> b=Timestamp('1986-04-18 00:00:00', tz=None).to_period(freq='M')
>>> b-a
1L
```

Answer (score 2):

If the dates are actually datetime objects try this:

```
b.month - a.month + (b.year - a.year)*12
```

You need to account for the years separately.

Answer (score 0):

If they aren't datetime objects:

```
t0 = '1986-03-31 00:00:00'
t1 = '1987-12-31 00:00:00'

month0 = int(t0.split("-")[1])
month1 = int(t1.split("-")[1])

year0 = int(t0.split("-")[0])
year1 = int(t1.split("-")[0])

monthdif = (year1-year0)*12 + (month1 - month0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.to_datetime('1986-03-31 00:00:00', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
b = pd.to_datetime('1986-04-18 00:00:00', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

mdiff = lambda x,y: 12*(x.year-y.year) + (x.month-y.month)

print("Difference between {} and {} is: {} months".format(b,a,mdiff(b,a)))
```

Difference between 1986-04-18 00:00:00 and 1986-03-31 00:00:00 is: 1 month(s)